# how let ViewModels injected with DI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

i'm using injection with Unity in my mvc projetc.
Now I want to apply DI on my ViewModels that I use to make UI.

When I want to instanciate one viewmodel, I 'm passing Dependencies trough parameter of the viewmodel's constructor. Is it right?

Example of controller:

```
private readonly IPersonnelAMBusiness _IPersonnelAMBusinessRepo;
        private readonly IAnomalyBusiness _IAnomalyBusinessRepo;
        private readonly IDocumentBusiness _IDocumentBusinessRepo;
        private readonly IMessageBusiness _IMessageBusinessRepo;
        private readonly ICockpitStatBusiness _ICockpitStatBusinessRepo;
        private readonly INatureBusiness _INatureBusinessRepo;
        private readonly IAuditBusiness _IAuditBusinessRepo;
        private readonly IInstallationBusiness _IInstallationBusinessRepo;
        private readonly IUnitBusiness _IUnitBusinessRepo;

        // Unity inject references
        public HomeController(IPersonnelAMBusiness personnelRepo, IAnomalyBusiness anomalyRepo, IDocumentBusiness docRepo, 
            IMessageBusiness msgRepo, ICockpitStatBusiness cockpitStatRepo, INatureBusiness natureRepo,
            IAuditBusiness auditRepo,IInstallationBusiness installRepo, IUnitBusiness unitRepo)
        {
            _IPersonnelAMBusinessRepo = personnelRepo;
            _IAnomalyBusinessRepo = anomalyRepo;
            _IDocumentBusinessRepo = docRepo;
            _IMessageBusinessRepo = msgRepo;
            _ICockpitStatBusinessRepo = cockpitStatRepo;
            _INatureBusinessRepo = natureRepo;
            _IAuditBusinessRepo = auditRepo;
            _IInstallationBusinessRepo = installRepo;
            _IUnitBusinessRepo = unitRepo;
        }

public ActionResult TopMenu()
        {
            TopMenuViewModel model = new TopMenuViewModel(_IPersonnelAMBusinessRepo, _IDocumentBusinessRepo, _IMessageBusinessRepo);
            model.SetMenuFor(SessionManager.matricule);
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_TopMenu.cshtml", model);
        }
```

Basically I have one BaseViewModel that host common UI lists , etc. This base viewmodel is used by lots of viewmodels (not the ViewModel I've put as example before).

Because ViewModel uses all my dependencies (+10), do I have to inject all dependencies from controller, even if controller only uses 1 of them? Or there is a way to say in Unity Config that ViewModels can do DI with Unity?

In Unity I've set dependencies like that:

```
 container.RegisterType<IEmailBusiness, EmailBusiness>();
 ...
 DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Thank you

Comment: reading this could help getting you gettings started with unity registrations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660894(v=pandp.20).aspx

Comment: and this answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/189192/148793

Comment: I'm of a mind that viewmodels should not have any external dependencies and should be populated using AutoMapper or directly projected into by linq queries.